# Flask jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined* [RESOLVED]

Tags: python, flask

**Edit:** okey guys after three hourse i resolve this problem...
problem  was in html  relied on
`**{{form.RegcheckEmial(name='email',placeholder='Email')}}**`
**name='email'** give me that erorr i resovled like this:

**in reg.html**

i removed

```
{{form.RegcheckEmial(name='email',placeholder='Email')}}
```

and replace this

```
{{form.RegcheckEmial(placeholder='Email')}}</br>
```

**in file.py**

i removed:

```
Email=request.form['email']
username=request.form['username']
password=request.form['password']
```

and replaced this:

```
   email=form.RegcheckEmial.data   
   user=form.Regcheckuser.data
   password=form.Recheckpassword.data
```

dHi Guys i have problem with flask , console  give me error such as
i don't know how to solve this problem, my html says my form is undefined
I want to check the validation of my input data and if the data has been entered successfully with validation, go to sending the data to my database
**classes**

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    checkEmial = StringField('checkEmial', validators=[InputRequired('A username is required!'), Length(min=5, max=50, message='Must be between 5 and 10 characters.'),Email(message='PLS ENETER CORRET Email')])
    checkPassword = PasswordField('checkPassword', validators=[InputRequired('Password is required!'),Length(min=6, max=30, message='type the stronger password')])

class RegisterForm(FlaskForm):
          RegcheckEmial=StringField('checkkEmiall',validators=[InputRequired('Please type value'),Length(min=5, max=50, message='Must be between 5 and 10 characters.'),Email(message='PLS ENETER CORRET Email')])
```

**File.py**

```
@app.route('/reg.html',methods=['POST'])
def Register():
    form=RegisterForm()        
    if form.validate_on_submit():
      if request.method=='POST':         
       Email=request.form['email']
   username=request.form['username']
   password=request.form['password']
            
   cur=mysql.connection.cursor()
   cur.execute('''INSERT INTO dane (Email,username,UserPassword) VALUES (%s , %s , %s)''',(Email , username , password))
   mysql.connection.commit() 
   cur.close()
   return redirect(url_for('index'))
   return render_template('reg.html',form=form)
```

**reg.html**

```
<div class="LoginSquare">
{% block content %}
    <form method='POST' >




                                    
{{ form.csrf_token }}
{{form.RegcheckEmial(name='email',placeholder='Email')}}  \
{% for error in form.RegcheckEmial.errors %}
<span style="color:red;">{{ error }}</br></span>
{% endfor %}
<div class="d1">
<input type='submit'name='Register' id='awdwd'class='wdawd'>
</div>
</form>
{%endblock%}
```

**index.html//(

```
this is my login page where I use LoginForm classes )**

 <form method='POST' action="{{ url_for('index') }}" >
                              <div class="page1">
                                    
                                    <img  src="/static/pages/useerr.png" width="50px" height="50px">
                              
                              </div>
                              <!-- {{form.csrf_token}} -->
                             
                              {{ form.csrf_token }}
                             
                              {{ form.checkEmial(placeholder='Email')}}</br>
                              
                              {% for error in form.checkEmial.errors %}
                                  <span style="color:red;">{{ error }}</br></span>
                              {% endfor %}
```

error console : jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined,in top-level template code
{% block content %}, File "c:\python39\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 474, in getattr
return getattr(obj, attribute)

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in code.

1. you don't have to use the filename as the route. It can be like "/register" or "/signup" and You will be able to access page by going to url like `www.site.com/register` if you use `/register` as route.
2. You have only allowed post request to the url and you will not be able to visit the site. It will give you error `405 method not allowed` error. You need to allow `get` request to url.

So your route should be:

```
@app.route('/register',methods=['POST','GET'])
```

You can go to `yoursite.com/register` to access the page.

Also I am assuming that you are visiting a wrong url as you haven't provided in your question where you haven't provided `form` variable to template.

Comment: yeah thank  but now i have error TypeError: wtforms.widgets.core.html_params() got multiple values for keyword argument 'name' :c

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste the form class.

Comment: yeah i added  also i have another class "LoginForm" whose help me to check data in my database